# Распасрить ссылку

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Привет. Есть ссылка такого рода:

```
mydoman.test/seopage.aspx?d=slovo+poiska
[{"keyword":"slovo poiska","term_id":"3129651","poisk_local":"570","poisk_global":"570"},
{"keyword":"slovo poiska tut","term_id":"28221200","poisk_local":"270","poisk_global":"330"}]
```

Ничего больше нет - это не xml. Как распасрить ссылку, чтобы выводило

```
 keyword, poisk_local, poisk_global
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

**Обновление**

[[@jikol](/users/14945/jikol)](/users/14945/jikol)

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: А на примере можно, а то ничего не выходит...

Comment: @jikol, обновил ответ.